# Select specific record or records with the same value in a column

Tags: mysql, select

I have this table with data:

```
NAME | GROUP
------------
a1   | A
a22  | A
c1   | C
c2   | C
s1   | NULL
t1   | NULL
```

How to select record named `a1` and if this record has a `group <> NULL` include also other items from the same group?

I've tried subquery:

```
SELECT `name`, `group` FROM `tbl`
WHERE (`name` = 'a1' AND `group` IS NULL) OR `group` = (SELECT `group` FROM `tbl` WHERE `name` = 'a1')
```

`EXPLAIN`:

```
id  select_type  table  type  possible_keys  key      key_len  ref    rows  
 1  PRIMARY      tbl    ALL   PRIMARY        NULL     NULL     NULL   6 Using where
 2  SUBQUERY     tbl    const PRIMARY        PRIMARY  386      const  1
```

This works but I'm not sure if it's 100% correct and efficient. Looking for a better solution, maybe with `JOIN`?

MySQL internals question: Is inner `SELECT` query executed for every searched record in the outer table? Is result of this query cached (like `SELECT SQL_CACHE` query)?

Comment: please post result of EXPLAIN

Comment: It is just me or this query, in case `a1`'s `group` is `NULL`, will return `a1`, `s1` and `t1`?

Comment: Yes the query is not very good at this, `NULL` test should be added

Comment: EXPLAIN added, NULL group fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following query will return a resultset that matches the specification.

```
SELECT DISTINCT COALESCE(t.name,s.name) AS `name`
  FROM `tbl` s
  LEFT
  JOIN `tbl` t
    ON t.group = s.group
 WHERE s.name = 'a1'
```

If a row with `name = 'a1'` exists in the table, that row will be returned.  The query will also return values of `name` that have a `group` value that matches any `group` value for a row with `name = 'a1'`.